# irregularities in insert, so why does my code not work?

Tags: php

When I want to get a letter from Ascii Code and get a number with a number like 8 and I'll get back to it, I'm having trouble, the answer is not printed correctly.
For example, I run the following code:

```
$a = "Milk";

for ($i = 0; $i < 4 ;$i++) {

  echo ord($a[$i]) . " + " . 8 . " = " . (ord($a[$i]) + 8) . "<br>";
  $a[$i] = ord($a[$i]) + 8;
  echo "$a[$i]";
}
```

The answer is as follows:

> ```
> 77 + 8 = 85
> 8105 + 8 = 113
> 1108 + 8 = 116
> 1107 + 8 = 115
> 1
> ```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Well the first line of your `for` loop seems OK, but I'm not sure what you're doing with the other two lines. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What is the desired output?

Comment: The output "looks" funny because there is no `<br>` on the second `echo`.

Comment: DinoCoderSaurus Thanks, I'm sorry very fun, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try using `intval(ord($a[$i]))` to turn the type from string to int.

Comment: I insert br tag front of line 5, Thanks